# How can I find the flying time for a projectile fired from some elevation and hitting an incline at a given angle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, projectile-motion

The problem is as follows:

> In the figure from below a projectile is launched from point labeled
>   $A$ with an initial speed of $30\frac{m}{s}$ making an angle of
>   $37^{\circ}$ (with the horizontal). An observer notices that the
>   projectile hits an incline making an angle of $90^{\circ}$ as depicted
>   in point labeled $B$. Find the flying time on seconds. (You may use
>   $g=10\frac{m}{s^{2}}$)

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&1.2\,s\\
2.&2.6\,s\\
3.&3.4\,s\\
4.&4.2\,s\\
5.&5.2\,s\\
\end{array}$

So far the only thing which I could come up with was to establish that the equation for the projectile would be as follows:

$y(t)=y_{o}+v_{o}\sin\omega t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$

Since the height isn't exactly given (i'm stuck) but for obvious reasons it cannot be zero. But I can fill the other terms.

$y(t)=y_{o}+v_{o}\sin37^{\circ} t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$

(Note: For this part I'm assuming an approximation of the $37-53-90$ triangle being $3-4-5$.)

$y(t)=y_{o}+30\left(\frac{3}{5}\right) t-\frac{1}{2}\left(10\right)t^2$

$y(t)=y_{o}+18 t-5t^2$

But now what?.

I think for this part I'm missing a concept which I don't know how to use the given hitting angle. Can somebody help me with this?.

Answer (score 1):

in horizontal direction:

$x=v_0\cdot cos(\alpha)\cdot t\Rightarrow t=\frac{x}{v_0 \cdot cos(\alpha)}$

in vertical direction:
$y=y_0 +v_0 \cdot sin(\alpha)-g\cdot \frac{t^2}{2}$

rearranging the terms of the quadratic in standard form:

$y=-\frac{g}{2\cdot v_0^2\cdot cos^2(\alpha)}\cdot x^2+tg(\alpha)\cdot x +y_0$

now the condition for the angle at point B is:
$\frac{dy}{dx}=-1$

which by differentiating y leads to:
$-\frac{g}{v_0^2cor^2(\alpha)}\cdot x+tg(\alpha)=-1$

which solves for x:

$x=\frac{1+tg(\alpha)}{g}\cdot v_0^2\cdot cos^2(\alpha)$

which further solves for t:

$t=\frac{1+tg(\alpha)}{g}\cdot v_0\cdot cos(\alpha)$

numerically:
$t=\frac{sin(37^0)+cos(37^0)}{10}\cdot 30\approx 4.2$

Comment: Interesting I didn't know that calculus could had been also used for this problem. But one must take into consideration the proportionality between the horizontal and vertical components and also the quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple equations relating the parameters of motion of a body under a constant acceleration. You've used the one whose standard form is $s=ut+\frac12 at^2$. But since you neither have nor need $s$ that's a dead end.

Try $v = u + at$ and don't forget the horizontal component of the motion.

Comment: But if I were to use that. What values should I put into?. I don't know how to use the trigonometric functions to be used in the equation that you had mentioned. Perhaps can you offer more guidance?. Because I'm still stuck on what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

You're not interested in the position at all, you're interested in the direction the projectile is going at a certain time.  According to my physics textbook, if a projectile is fired with velocity $v_0$ with an angle of elevation $\theta$, then at time $t$:

$$v_x=v_0\cos\theta\\v_y=v_0\sin\theta-gt$$

Based on the diagram, we want the ending angle to be $-45^\circ=\tan^{-1}(-1)$, so we will set $-v_y=v_x$ in the above.  (We will take advantage of the fact that $37^\circ$ is approximately the angle of a 3-4-5 right triangle to grossly simplify our trig.)

$$-v_0\cos\theta=v_0\sin\theta-gt\\-30(0.8)=30(0.6)-(10)t\\-42=-10t\\t=4.2\,\textrm s$$

Comment: Nice solution but a couple of questions. Why shouldn't I be interested in the position for this problem?. Typically the way to solve problems involving projectiles the equation to use is the position. So that when a given condition based on the vector does it forces it to use the solution you proposed?. Out of curiosity, regarding the book that you mentioned, was it Jearl Walker's Physics?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell The main reason that we shouldn't be interested in finding the position of the projectile is that we have no data about it.  We don't know how high the wall is, we don't know how far the wall is from the start of the hill, and we don't know how high the hill is.  The only data we have is related to the angle of the projectile, so we're stuck with using it.  And, no, the physics textbook on my shelf is Sears, Zemansky, and Young.

Comment: Gee I was about the mention the book you quoted. It turns out that to solve these kinds of problems the position equation is not mandatory to be used. I was confused at why you used $\tan^{-1}(-1)$ instead of $\tan(-45^{\circ}=-1$. But I believe the reason why this angle was used is due the angle the incline does with the horizontal Am I right?. Had not been that angle the proportionality between the vertical and horizontal speeds would had been different right?. I think it is critical in this problem to consider the quadrant where it lies the angle in this scenario is in the IV.

Answer (score 0):

hint

you start with an horizontal speed $v_h $ and a vertical speed $v_v$ that are easily determined.
$v_h$remains constant.
$v_v$ diminuishes by $gt$ from the initial value.
After a certain $t$ their ratio shall reach $tan(-45°)$ .

Thus ..

(since you asked for the solution)

$$
\eqalign{
  & v_{\,h}  = 30\cos \left( {37^ \circ  } \right)\quad v_{\,v}  = 30\sin \left( {37^ \circ  } \right) - gt  \cr 
  & {{30\sin \left( {37^ \circ  } \right) - gt} \over {30\cos \left( {37^ \circ  } \right)}} =  - \tan \left( {45^ \circ  } \right) =  - 1  \cr 
  & t = {{30} \over g}\left( {\cos \left( {37^ \circ  } \right) + \sin \left( {37^ \circ  } \right)} \right) \approx 4.2 \cr} 
$$

Comment: It could had a better help if you added an equation from where to begin with.

Comment: I thought the hint was enough, anyway I added the answer

Comment: @G Cab I'm stuck at **how** do we establish that the ratio must be $\tan45^{\circ}$. Is it because of the $90^{\circ}$ angle that speed does with the incline or is it because the angle the incline does with the horizontal or is it because of both reasons?

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: because of both: we are using in fact the angle of the speed wrt the horizontal at the beginning and at the end: +37 and minus 45